# Move folders that have more than one file into another directory

Tags: sh

[POWER SHELL ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbR5M.jpg) [Picture of code and directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mVhO.jpg)

I would like to create a batch file that moves all folders that contain more than one file to another directory.

I tried the code below

```sh
mkdir "OOOO3_MORE_THAN_ONE"
for dir in *; do 
    # if the file is a directory
    if [ -d "$dir" ]; then 
        # count number of files
        count=$(find "$dir" -type f | wc -l) 
        #i f count=2 then move 
        if [ "$count" -le 1 ]; then 
            # move dir 
            mv -v "$dir" /completepath/"OOOO3_MORE_THAN_ONE" 
        fi
    fi
done
```

I just get a new folder without any folders inside.  The folders with multiple files did not move to the new directory

I also tried the below code, it's a little different, but still resulted in an empty folder

```
#! /bin/bash -p

shopt -s nullglob   # glob patterns that match nothing expand to nothing
shopt -s dotglob    # glob patterns expand names that start with '.'

destdir='subset'

[[ -d $destdir ]] || mkdir -- "$destdir"

for dir in * ; do
    [[ -L $dir ]] && continue               # Skip symbolic links
    [[ -d $dir ]] || continue               # Skip non-directories
    [[ $dir -ef $destdir ]] && continue     # Skip the destination dir.

    numfiles=$(find "./$dir//." -type f -print | grep -c //)
    (( numfiles > 1 )) && mv -v -- "$dir" "$destdir"
done
```

Comment: **"that contain more than one file"**,  `if [ "$count" -gt 1 ]; then ...`  move.

Comment: I replaced line 7 and also tried to replace line 8 with your suggestions, but it didn't work.  I'm not sure exactly where I should be placing it.

Comment: You want to move directories that contain more than one file. So a `$count` *greater than 1* is the test you need to determine it. So in your original post changing `if [ "$count" -le 1 ]; then` to `if [ "$count" -gt 1 ]; then` should have worked.

Comment: I tried it, but still no files in the directory.  I have posted an image link at the top of the post that has code and directory results

Answer (score 0):

Alright, you have two problems (as originally posted).

**(1)** you are attempting to move to `/completepath/OOOO3_MORE_THAN_ONE` after creating `"OOOO3_MORE_THAN_ONE"` in the ***current working directory***. Unless you are executing the script in `/completepath` when the directory `./OOOO3_MORE_THAN_ONE` is created, your calls to `mv -v "$dir" /completepath/"OOOO3_MORE_THAN_ONE"`will fail. (the double-quotes are superfluous here)

**(2)** you have a "chicken-and-the-egg" problem because you:

```
mkdir "OOOO3_MORE_THAN_ONE"
```

before you call:

```
for dir in *; do
```

(`OOOO3_MORE_THAN_ONE` is included in `'*'`, but not excluded before your calls to `find` and `mv`)

So you will effectively try and move `OOOO3_MORE_THAN_ONE` below itself when its name is reached in your list.

**So How To Correct the Problems?**

Rearrange your code. Since your Question is tagged `[sh]` (POSIX shell), you do not have the benefit of arrays available to pre-store the `count` and `dir` names, but you can always use a temporary file created with `mktemp`. You will want to read through each directory entry identified with `for dir in *` and write all `count` and `dir` information out to your temporary file **before** you start changing the directory structure. Then you can simply loop over the entries in your temporary file, checking if `$count -gt 1` and moving to your new `$dir` if so, e.g.

```
#!/bin/sh

## initialize newdir from 1st argument (or default: OOOO3_MORE_THAN_ONE)
newdir="${1:-OOOO3_MORE_THAN_ONE}"

## set your complete path from 2nd arg (or '.' by default)
cmpltpath="${2:-.}"

## now create a temporary file to hold count dirname pairs
tmpfile=$(mktemp)

for dir in *; do    ## write count and dirname pairs to temporary file
    [ -d "$dir" ] && echo "$(find "$dir" -type f | wc -l) $dir" >> "$tmpfile"
done

## now create the directory to move to using cmpltpath, exit on failure
mkdir -p "$cmpltpath/$newdir" || exit 1

## read count and dirname from tmpfile & move if count > 1
while read -r count dir || [ -n "$dir" ]; do
    ## if count=2 then move 
    if [ "$count" -gt 1 ]; then 
        ## move to dir 
        mv -v "$dir" "$cmpltpath/$newdir" 
    fi
done < "$tmpfile"

rm "$tmpfile"   ## tidy up and remove tmpfile (or set trap after mktemp)
```

(**note:** the script takes the directory name to create and move files below as the first argument (positional parameter) for the script, and the complete path (absolute or relative) to precede your new directory)

(**also note:** if you have bash (or another advanced shell that supports associative arrays), you can simply save the directory name and count within an associative array keyed on directory name and avoid using a temporary file altogether)

**Original directory**

Using a directory tree where each subdirectory `d1, d2, d3` has `1, 2 or 3` files below them, e.g.:

```
$ tree
.
├── d1
│   └── file1
├── d2
│   ├── file1
│   └── file2
├── d3
│   ├── file1
│   ├── file2
│   └── file3
└── mvscript.sh
```

**Example Use/Resulting Directory Structure**

Now running the script will move all directories with greater than 1 file below into your new directory:

```
$ sh mvscript.sh
'd2' -> './OOOO3_MORE_THAN_ONE/d2'
'd3' -> './OOOO3_MORE_THAN_ONE/d3'

$ tree
.
├── OOOO3_MORE_THAN_ONE
│   ├── d2
│   │   ├── file1
│   │   └── file2
│   └── d3
│       ├── file1
│       ├── file2
│       └── file3
├── d1
│   └── file1
└── mvscript.sh
```

**Your Second Approach**

Your second approach is not bad, but unless you have some special requirements and need to match dot-files, you may want to adjust `GLOBIGNORE` instead of setting `dotglob` as specified in `man bash` under the `Pathname Expansion` section. Also note there is no space between the `#!` and `/bin/bash` on the first line.

A basic tweak of your second attempt could be:

```
#!/bin/bash

destdir='subset'

mkdir -p -- "$destdir" || exit 1

for dir in * ; do
    [[ -L $dir ]] && continue               # Skip symbolic links
    [[ -d $dir ]] || continue               # Skip non-directories
    [[ $dir -ef $destdir ]] && continue     # Skip the destination dir.

    numfiles=$(find "$dir" -type f -printf ".\n" | wc -l)
    (( numfiles > 1 )) && mv -v -- "$dir" "$destdir"
done
```

**Example Use/Output**

A similar test would result in:

```
$ bash mvscript2.sh
'd2' -> 'subset/d2'
'd3' -> 'subset/d3'

$ tree
.
├── d1
│   └── file1
├── mvscript2.sh
└── subset
    ├── d2
    │   ├── file1
    │   └── file2
    └── d3
        ├── file1
        ├── file2
        └── file3
```

Comment: David,  Thank you for the very thorough response.  I fear this might be way above my skil levell, I will give the frist part a shot when I get home. I have over 17,000 folders so I want to make sure I get it right before i mess things up :)

Comment: You can generate as many test cases as you like. Just create a new directory and you can build your test cases with, e.g. `for ((i=1; i<4; i++)); do mkdir -p "d$i"; for ((j=0; j<i; j++)); do touch "d$i/file$((j+1))"; done; done` (which is how I built the test case above). Also, if you have bash or some other shell, using an associative array rather than a temporary file will speed things up a bit. Drop another comment if you run into problems.

Comment: Also note, your 2nd attempt is not bad at all, but you should get rid of `"./$dir//."` and simply use `"$dir"` in the `find` command. No need for `--` in `mkdir` unless `$dir` can begin with `'-'` (it doesn't hurt, it is just strange, generally you want `mkdir -p`) And there is no space between `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: I just installed Bash on my Win 10 so I would like to try it with that.  I am a bit confused though, how does bash work if I am placing this code into a .bat file?

Comment: Well -- it doesn't. `.bat` and "batch" files are script files for the DOS interpreter. You are interested in shell scripts to run in Ubuntu though WSL. That uses the Linux shell (bash in your case) and shell scripts generally have `.sh` extensions (more to make editor syntax highlighting work that anything to do with the script). DOS batch and Linux shell have completely different syntax, but both fill the same role for their operating system. You will use bash within WSL and DOS in the Windows Command Prompt. (and you will see why bash is so much more capable than DOS batch `:)`

Comment: The line at the top `#!/bin/bash` chooses the interpreter the remaining commands in the file will be processed with.  (bash, perl, awk, php, etc...) all provided interpreters. When you run a shell script you want `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/bin/sh` if you have no bash. For DOS batch files, nothing is needed on the first line, because there is only one interpreter -- DOS.

Comment: David, I thought all this was going into a .bat file.  I guess that's why it wasn't working.  That's what I was trying to do as I don't have much experience using shells (Powershell/Bash etc..)   With that being said I tried that on Powershell.  I created a .ps1 file with the code above and ran it in Powershell but it had no effect on my directories.  Please see the uploaded image.     After messing with Powershelll it is a little interesting and seems fun in a weird way

Comment: Yikes! All shells are different animals. (the only related ones are the Linux flavors). DOS batch command language using the .bat extension, is completely different from PowerShell using the .ps1 extensions is completely different from Linux shells (where the "*pound-bang*" on the first line, e.g. `#!/bin/bash`, identifies the interpreter for the rest of the file and the extension is irrelevant). Within WSL running Ubuntu, you will be using Linux shells. Bash is installed by default. Keep them all separate. Run your bash script with `bash scriptname args` (as shown in my answer `:)`

Comment: David,  I am embarrassed to say, but it took me 8hrs to figured out how to change directories in Bash.  I was determined to at least figure that out by myself.   Long story short, your code worked perfectly.   17,000 folders moved correctly.  Thank you very much.  I am still new here so if you would not mind, can you please tell me what is proper etiquette to mark answered and leave reputation remarks?  I find it amazing what can be done if you know how to do it in this command line stuff.  I hope to learn a little more.

Comment: Learning bash, or C or any language is a journey, not a race. The command-prompt can look pretty daunting at first.... But just like anything else, take the time and go though a tutorial or two [Bash Guide for Beginners](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/) and [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/), the fish-out-of-water feeling will quickly fade. Then always remember `man commandx` (e.g. `man cd`) to pull up the manual page for any command you need to use, and you will advance quickly. Then learn `sed` and `awk` - cryptic, but lifesavers.